# Crontab - Unusual config - Skip a small weekly time window

Tags: linux, centos, cron

I have a business requirement to run an unorthodox crontab schedule as follows:

Everyday run a script from 1-21

Everyday but saturday, run from 21-0

So I was thinking this would work:

```
5       1-20    *       *       *       /path/to/script.php
5       21-00   *       *       0-5,7   /path/to/script.php
```

Or is there a better way?

-- Edit --

Blah this is what happens when you post before morning coffee, there is no 7 in crontab syntax as its 0-6, so the entry should be:

```
5       *    *       *       0-5       /path/to/script.php
5       1-21   *       *       6   /path/to/script.php
```

Comment: If it works, everything is fine. No need to over-optimize this.

Comment: Im questioning the syntax.

Comment: The syntax you have will run it once per hour (5 minutes after the top of the hour) for the hours between and including 1-20 every day.  Also run it 5 minutes after the hour between and including 21-00 (not sure how that's going to work, 00 is the next day) every day except Saturday.  I would just make one line from 0-23 for days 0-5,7 and another for Saturday only that runs 1-21 if I was putting it in myself.

Comment: @yoonix: Thanks, I was wondering the same thing about sat myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't appear to meet your requirements as it doesn't run the script every day at 21 (it doesn't run on Saturday at 21).

Your requirement appears to simplify to everyday bar Saturday run a script at 5 minutes past the hour. On a Saturday only run from 1-21 e.g.

```
5 * * * 1-5,7 /path/to/script
5 1-21 * * 6 /path/to script
```

Comment: Blah, you can tell it's been a long week... even longer that I am trying to add an extra day. There is no 7, only 0-6, so your answer makes more sense, check edit to OP.

Comment: @MikePurcell: Sunday can be 0 or 7 so my answer _was_ slightly wrong in that it specified 0 and 7 but that's easily fixed.